# How to subtracting-2-columns-different-tables in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 tables for inventory and other for sales actually I want to tell how many items still in store by doing that I have to subtract the quantity column of inventory table from quantity column from sales table any 1 with any idea how I can do this

```
Inventory                                                   SALES

items quantity                                           items quantity
A      50                                                 A      30
B      70                                                 B      20
D       60                                                D       10
C       40                                                C       30
```

Create a new table with new columns for answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (inventory.quantity - sales.quantity) as leftQty
From inventory
Join sales
on sales.items=inventory.items
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can create a new table if it doesn't exist. like the code below.

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM newTable)
    DROP TABLE #newTable CREATE TABLE newTable(Item VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY, Diff varchar(255));", con))
```

If you already have the table to store the result..you can run the following command using a similar code.
.
you said you need to

> subtract the quantity column of inventory table from quantity column from sales tab

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(string.Format("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO newTable ( item, diff)  SELECT item, Sales.Quantity - Inventory.Quantity WHERE Sales.Item = Inventory.Item));", con))
```

I haven't compiled this code. Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Shan sorry for the delay  to reply but the  code has syntax error am wishing can i apply it on data gried view tables